# Android application development on Eclipse. SQLite null pointer exception

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I've tried modeling both the database calls being made in the activity and the database handling class itself after so many tutorials online that I've just given up completely.

I have an activity that gets user input from the `EditText` box then pass the data to the database handler class.  The data is used to create a table in the the database, with the table's name being the `EditText`'s input.

So in a nut-shell the `Activity` gets input from the user then creates a table in the database named after said input.  I've got two classes here, the calling activity (first) and then the database handler(second).  I'd seriously make a paypal donation to anyone who can show me what I'm doing wrong.  I've included the source I'm talking about in a pastebin link.

http://pastebin.com/wmbwGFW0

http://pastebin.com/e2P91Spe

Comment: sorry for my previous comment for the code.can you please tell me on which line exactly you are getting nullpointer or can you please provide the logcat messages?ty

Comment: At the line that calls the db. Inside of the activity's else clause

Comment: Thanks for helping me out by the way.  Here's a pastebin link to the logcat output.    http://pastebin.com/qA8g5Cw5

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that you are not opening the database to write from the activity class.
try to do the following in your NewDragonActivity class and see if it works:

instead of:

```
basicsBuilder.addBasicsData(1, name);
```

try doing this

```
basicsBuilder = DbBasics.getInstance();
basicsBuilder.open(this);               
basicsBuilder.addBasicsData(1,name);
basicsBuilder.close();
```

Comment: Nah, that's not it.  I had an open statement before, I had just removed it before posting to pastebin and forgot to add it back.  I added what you've suggested to my code, and I'm still getting a null pointer exception